# Does is required to verify domain for aws SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am new to SES and i want to keep delivery and read log of my all mail which is sent by my aws smtp detail, so **is required to verify domain for aws SES**.?

I created topic, created subscription but i didn't get email delivery status.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've verified email domain before SNS topic creation. TXT (Text) has been added in DNS records. SNS-topic works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've added yourself as a subscriber you will also need to accept that subscription before you receive emails.

Comment: i am using http method for this

Comment: Try looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html#SendMessageToHttp.confirm